# Address format error on Mumbai’s polygonscan

Tags: solidity, polygon

I have a write function to add an array of addresses, I put for example this:

["0x6e910B4503B5C2576b1395ed3461c58721C09195"]

And the polygo matic scan , says this error:

invalid address (arg="addresses", coderType="address", value="0x6e910B4503B5C2576b1395ed3461c58721C09195"")

[image]

However , when i switch to Rinkeby network , no error prompt and write successfully.

```
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x3b3e3da68c6d5093d272cf8ca4973ac8422f2da6
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: hi , pls help to advise

Answer (score 0):

It's [0x6e910B4503B5C2576b1395ed3461c58721C09195] on polygonscan, not ["0x6e910B4503B5C2576b1395ed3461c58721C09195"].

Comment: add more info please